# GridView showing double on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that is supposed to refresh using

```
        gridView.DataSource = null;
        gridView.DataBind();
```

before binding it to the updated datasource (which is a DataTable).

and then

```
gridView.DataSource = newDataTable;
gridView.DataBind();
```

The problem is that it won't clear and from time to time I get a table on top of another table (the one on top is the updated one, the bottom one is the data before the 2nd DataBind).

Appreciate your help!

Comment: guess you could 'force' the "clear" operation by removing all the rows in the gridview (while rows.count > 0, deleterow(0) or whatever) but if it's intermittent, i wonder if the 'clear' code isn't getting called in some paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually hook up to the data-source updated or inserted event and then call the DataBind method directly after the Insert and Update has executed.

You can also try adding this before you reload the grid, although the databind should refresh it:

gridView.Dispose();

Answer (score 0):

```
        gv_BCDashboard.Columns.Clear(); -- Clearing the Columns and rebinding.
        foreach (DataColumn col in bcDashboard.Columns)
        {
            //Declare the bound field and allocate memory for the bound field.
            BoundField bfield = new BoundField();

            //Initalize the DataField value.
            bfield.DataField = col.ColumnName;

            //Initialize the HeaderText field value.
            bfield.HeaderText = col.ColumnName;

            //Add the newly created bound field to the GridView.
            gv_BCDashboard.Columns.Add(bfield);
        }
                    
        gv_BCDashboard.DataSource = bcDashboard;
        gv_BCDashboard.DataBind();

    }
```